# How to setup automatic code formatting

Tags: c#, code-formatting

How to bring the automatic formatting of code in C# to this kind of

```
code
{\t\t code \n
\t\t code \t\t}
```

[image]

Comment: Try pressing `Ctrl + k + d`

Comment: Tasks not available now, how to repair it?

Comment: What IDE is this for?

Comment: That formatting looks awful, any reason you want to diverge so drastically from fairly common standards?

Comment: Try it, for me readability increased significantly. Of course this is a matter of habit. But since I writing of less a week, and for me common standards do not matter. Sorry if that sounded rude. And so I want to reinvent the wheel, because it works in the best way for me.
I wonder whether there  is a automation tools to work with the format of code. For what in the process of work is not distracted to the personal dynamic of standard.
That's it.

Comment: Sorry, my IDE is Visual Studio'13